# Sublime Text 3 Multiline Method Folding

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, multiline, folding, character-limit

SO...

Sublime Text has the built in ability to fold methods, but as soon as the method declaration spans multiple lines it loses this ability. Does anyone know about a plugin or a way to make this work? Specifically I am running into this with ruby (and my team adheres to a strict style guide regarding line length), but the language shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of clicking on the down arrow that appears in the gutter next to the first line of the function definition, all you need to do is put your cursor on one of the function's indented lines (not the indented function parameters, but in the function definition itself) and use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> key binding (on OS X use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>) to fold the function and its parameters. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> on OS X) to unfold, or you can click the sideways arrow next to the `def` line.

So, this:

[image: code before folding]

becomes this:

[image: code after folding]

Comment: Perfect, that's even better as I prefer shortcuts and does not require any change to the code, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this formatting

```
def example(   # <--- folds parameters here
  param, 
  param
)              # <--- folds method body here
  foo
  bar
  qux
end
```

The language does matter as far as I know, method folding is part of the language specific configuration. At least it used to be in previous versions.