# PEP8 function definitions and Sublime Text 3 code folding

Tags: python, sublimetext3, pep8

If I have a function definition which spans multiple lines to keep in with PEP8 such as this:

```
def compile_time_table(daily_id=999, weekly_id=999, yearly_id=999, user=None,
                      zone_id=None, zone_name=None):
```

Sublime Text looses its ability to fold the definition:

[image: Sublime Text 3 not folding]

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Try `ctrl-shift-[` on the first function body line (i.e. immediately after the definition). Seems to work for me with US keyboard layout (but I prefer different layout). Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558450/sublime-text-3-multiline-method-folding

Comment: I'm in Germany so most standard shortcuts involving [ ] / \ < > are inaccessible

Comment: Yes, I know the problem with national layouts.... Anyway, shortcuts can be edited in `Preferences -> KeyBindings` if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sublime Text 3, there is a `Code Folding` option in the menu where `EDIT` resides. Click on it and choose `Code Folding`. Here you can see the folding methods and shortcut
keys. Use the keybord shortcuts `Ctrl + K` and `Ctrl + 1` to fold all your functions, unless you changed the default shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks! Really should have thought of that myself :)

Comment: It is a little bit hidden I guess. I had to search for it myself not too long ago.